# how to OSI model works

Tags: networking, ethernet, osi

Good day!

I am studying OSI model.

I have some confused questions.

At the network layer, data can be divided into multiple packets and reassembled again.

Reassembly means to be assembled 'in order', but packets may be out order in UDP, the transport layer protocol.

My question is:

- Where do you reassemble the packet?
- If you work at the network layer, why is UDP out order?
- What the network layer and the transport layer do

Comment: read RFC for [udp](https://tools.ietf.org/html/rfc768) and  [Communication Layers](https://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc1122.txt) . learn how to use google

Comment: @robert I think I am confused datagrams and packets.

The network layer divides the datagram into several packets, assembles the packets in order, and sends them to the transport layer. And that the higher layer checks whether the datagram sent is reliable.

Is that correct?

Comment: TCP/IP is not an example of the OSI model. It has its own, prior model.

Answer (score 1):

You're mixing up different functions and layers.

In the network layer, *oversized packets* can be *fragmented*, to be reassembled by the destination's network layer. This function copes with the problem that the MTU can become smaller than the actual packet during hop-to-hop transport (in IPv4 - IPv6 removed this function in favor of path MTU discovery).

At the *transport layer* there are (connection-oriented) protocols like TCP that divide a continuous data stream into segments that are tracked by both source and destination. The data stream is reconstructed by the destination when all necessary segments have arrived. Lost segments are resent using the tracking.

A UDP datagram may require fragmentation along the way, requiring reassembly by the destination. However, if one of the fragments is lost there's no reassembly and no datagram gets passed to the application - it's lost.

UDP is a 'fire and forget' protocol transporting datagrams. Different datagrams may take different network routes, possibly causing them to arrive out of order.

When a TCP segment is lost it fails acknowledgment by the destination. This makes the source resend the segment. Whether the packet carrying the segment required fragmentation or not doesn't matter - only when all fragments have arrived is the reassembled segment passed to TCP. TCP then ACKs the segment and passes the data to the application.

TCP also reconstructs the order of the segments, so the data stream is exactly like it was sent. For this, segments are numbered and when they arrive out-of-order, the TCP (transport) layer resorts them.